# Backup dos idiomas

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron

Este script pero me hace un Backup.

Sin embargo, lo hace con dos idiomas: por ejemplo `Backup-Lunes.tar.gz` y a la siguiente semana `Backup-Monday.tar.gz` y no reemplaza el primero.

```
#!/bin/sh
####################################
#
# Backup to NFS mount script.
#
####################################

# What to backup. 
backup_files="/home /var/spool/mail /etc /root /boot /opt"

# Where to backup to.
dest="/mnt/backup"

# Create archive filename.
day=$(date +%A)
hostname=$(hostname -s)
archive_file="$hostname-$day.tgz"

# Print start status message.
echo "Backing up $backup_files to $dest/$archive_file"
date
echo

# Backup the files using tar.
tar czf $dest/$archive_file $backup_files

# Print end status message.
echo
echo "Backup finished"
date

# Long listing of files in $dest to check file sizes.
ls -lh $dest
```

El Script del Backup se ejecuta mediante otro Script que tiene otros procesos. Pero Basicamente seria:

```
echo "--------------------------------------" >> $LOG
echo " Copia de seguridad" >> $LOG
echo "--------------------------------------" >> $LOG

$PATH/Bin/backup.sh  >> $LOG 2>> $ERR
```

La tarea del cron es la siguiente:

```
0 5 * * * /APLI10/Bin/netcron
```

y mi locale

```
bbaa> locale
LANG=es_ES.ISO8859-1
LC_CTYPE="es_ES.ISO8859-1"
LC_NUMERIC="es_ES.ISO8859-1"
LC_TIME="es_ES.ISO8859-1"
LC_COLLATE="es_ES.ISO8859-1"
LC_MONETARY="es_ES.ISO8859-1"
LC_MESSAGES="es_ES.ISO8859-1"
LC_PAPER="es_ES.ISO8859-1"
LC_NAME="es_ES.ISO8859-1"
LC_ADDRESS="es_ES.ISO8859-1"
LC_TELEPHONE="es_ES.ISO8859-1"
LC_MEASUREMENT="es_ES.ISO8859-1"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="es_ES.ISO8859-1"
LC_ALL=
/data/backup/
```

Comment: ¿cómo lo ejecutas? Parece que de forma distinta entre una y otra vez, para que `date +%A` coja el locale en inglés una vez y otra en castellano

Comment: I run it from another script that does different tasks and within one of them the backup.

Inside cronJob
echo "------------------------------------------" >> $LOG
echo " Backup" >> $LOG
echo "------------------------------------------" >> $LOG

ABNETPATH/Bin/backup.sh >> $LOG 2>> $ERR

That this programmed in the cron of the user.

0 5 * * * /APLI10/Bin/cronJob

Comment: (estamos en [es.so], hablemos en castellano :P) Pues entonces indica qué comandos exactos utilizas en el cron, así como cuál es el locale del usuario. Dale a [edit] para añadir detalles a la pregunta, no los pongas en comentarios.

Comment: :P Disculpame se me paso, voy agregar los datos para que se vea todo el problema completo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto solo puede pasar si cambia el locale entre diferentes ejecuciones de tu script. No sé ni cómo, ni por qué, eso dependerá de tu sistema, pero la solución simple es forzar el locale que quieres. Simplemente añádelo al `date`:

```
day=$(LC_ALL=es_ES.ISO8859-1 date +%A)
```

O, si lo quieres en inglés:

```
day=$(LC_ALL=C date +%A)
```